# Variables in Lambda expression are mixed up on compile time

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I've been getting a `java.lang.VerifyError` on a newly compiled class. I tried with `-Xverify:none` what resulted in a `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError`. I finally decided to decompile my compiled class and got a pretty unexpected result.

The original lambda source (slightly altered to the relevant parts)

```
// field
private final Set<MediaPoolContainerModel> currentModels = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());


//within method
for (final ContainerModel container : containers) {
    if (container.isMandatory()) {
        currentModels.add(container);
    }

    final Component component = createComponentForContainer(container, checkEvent -> {

        if (checkEvent.isChecked()) {
            currentModels.add(container);
        } else {
            currentModels.remove(container);
        }
        editorListener.onValueChanged(currentModels);

    });
}
```

The EventListener interface (which is implemented by the lambda here) looks like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface EventListener<T extends Event> {
    void onEvent(T event) throws Exception;
}
```

Now here comes what really surprises me. The decompiled class output:

```
while(var11.hasNext()) {
    ContainerModel container = (ContainerModel)var11.next();
    if (container.isMandatory()) {
        this.currentModels.add(container);
    }

    Component component = createComponentForContainer(container, (checkEvent) -> {
        if (checkEvent.isChecked()) {
            this.currentModels.add(editorListener);
        } else {
            this.currentModels.remove(editorListener);
        }

        checkEvent.onValueChanged(this.currentModels);
    });
}
```

You can observe, that the capture `container` is no longer in the lambda, despite being used in the source code. `editorListener` (which has a completely different type to begin with) is used in it's place. The reason for the `IncompatibleClassChangeException` is obvious now, seeing that `onValueChanged` is called on the `checkEvent` instead of the `editorListener`.

Is this a grave compiler bug and if so, has anybody an idea what the reason might be and how this may be reproduced? Is there a bug ticket already? Are there any more steps that I can do to investigate the problem? Or did I do an obvious mistake that I just didn't know about yet?

Switching to an anonymous class does prevent the issue, but I find it still interesting to find out why this happens when using a lambda.

built using java1.8.0_161

Comment: If you get an error, you should include that error in your question (exact message and stack trace). Further, you should try to include an example capable of reproducing the problem. And specify, which decompiler you’ve used.

Comment: Just a guess, there might be a name hiding issue somewhere. What is `editorListener` and what are the parameters for `createComponentForContainer`? Try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Holger Yes, the problem is that there is no message, just the exception. The stack trace contains no valuable information at all. The VerifyError that I get literally just points to the bytecode, where the invalid call `checkEvent.onValueChanged(this.currentModels);` is made, nothing more. I didn't expect it to be useful so I excluded it since it's just a huge dump.
@SeanVanGorder `editorListener` is `EditorListener` from hybris 5.7, this is within an `CockpitEditorRenderer`. I'd love to make a working example, but I fail to reproduce it in a test project. If you have any advice, let me know

Comment: Did you find the cause and resolve the issue in the end? If yes, it would be good to post it as an answer.

Comment: Sadly, this remains unresolved. I worked around it by moving it into its own class file.